# Loading NSMutableArray in UITableViewController with Search bar crashing - iOS5 with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, nsmutablearray

I'm loading a `NSMutableArray` into a `UITableViewController` with a search bar in iOS 5. If I fill the array as code below and click over the search bar, it works perfectly:

```
[placesOutputArray addObject:@"object1"];
[placesOutputArray addObject:@"object2"];
[placesOutputArray addObject:@"object3"];
[placesOutputArray addObject:@"object4"];
```

`customSearchArray` is the data array loaded in `UITableView` delegate methods.

But, if I fill the array as the next way and click over the search bar:

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
   [placesOutputArray addObject:@"TestContent"];
```

It's crashing when I click over the search bar:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds for empty array'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x33d9a8bf 0x33fea1e5 0x33ce3b6b 0xa1d1 0x371a39cb 0x371a2aa9 0x3718977b 0x371896c3 0x37189277 0x37184e7b 0x37184bf9 0x37302b0f 0x33d95813 0x33d8e72f 0

I saw that the problem is at cellForRowAtIndexPath UITableView delegate method, because first screen only shows 9 cells. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It was a problem related with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and mutable objects. Solved checking the `UITableViewCells` and making a mutablecopy.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of `NSArray` are immutable. Use `NSMutableArray` instead. To put it more obvious, change placesOutputArray to be `NSMutableArray` from `NSArray` and don't forget to allocate memory for it appropriately `self.placesOutputArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Eugene. I've used NSMutableArray instead of NSArray and I've allocated placesOutputArray with self.placesOutputArray = [NSMutableArray array]; but stills crashing. I'm using ios5 with Automatic Reference Counting. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> But, if I fill the array as the next way and click over the search
>   bar:

I don't see how your code fills the same array.  The snippet you provided looks like it initializes placesOutputArray, not customSearchArray.  Do you think the answer is as simple as that?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Sorry danh, the fill of the NSMutableArray was over the object placesOutputArray and not customSearchArray, it was my fault. I was making reference to the way of filling the array. I've modified results object to NSMutableArray but still crashing. If I fill placesOutputArray harcoding the string all works perfect, but for example if I fill it into a for loop, it crashes. Any suggestion?